# Embedding a Vue.js app inside an Android WebView

Tags: javascript, android, vue.js, webview

I have an android app launching a Webview. I have some sample code in Vue.js that I want to integrate and run in that Webview. I tried to find a way to do so without modifying the vue.js sample, with no luck.

I found code to communicate info between the javascript running in the WebView and the android app, but I got lost adding Vue.js to the equation instead of plain javascript.